# Server Maintenance schedule with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am busy creating a maintenance schedule with the help of PowerShell.

At the moment I have a script [click!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx) that creates a txt file containing all our servers in our Active Directory

```
$strFilter = '(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*)'
```

My goal is to email the names of servers that need maintenance that day. The formula will be like:

`x servers in Active Directory / 5 working days = y servers a day / 12 weeks = z servers that day`

So every server gets maintenance once per three months

Ofcourse I will check if there are any new servers & replace the old file with a new file. But for now I am stuck / figuring out where to start to get my formula working in PowerShell.

My code:

```
function listAllServers{
    $strFilter = '(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*)'

    $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry #"LDAP://dc=action, dc=local" 

    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
    $objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objSearcher.SearchScope = 'Subtree'

    $colProplist = 'name'
    foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

    #Writing all server-names to file..
    foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
        {$objItem = $objResult.Properties; $objItem.name | Out-File C:\Servers.txt -append}
}
listAllServers

Get-Content C:\Servers.txt | Measure-Object -Line
```

Please give me your thoughts. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? It's pretty unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that! I am stuck at how to convert my formula into PowerShell code.